# Is there a way to merge many HBASE regions?

Tags: hbase

I have an HBase table that has a small-region size (`hbase.hregion.max.filesize=1GB`) so I've ended up with many 1000s of regions.

I know there is a command line tool that would merge 2 regions.

Is there a tool that would merge all the regions into a smaller set of regions.  For example, merge regions until each region is 10GB?

Or do I need to write my own utility?

Answer (score 0):

we had a case which was remarkably similar. For small tables , we ended up doing CopyTable to recreate the tables , for large ones you may end up rolling up a script of your own.

P.S. You can lookup patent :CN104199901A for some ideas (I am not the author , but there are scripts that you can see as to how some of these scripts were rolled up)